# Android GPU Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

Emulator without GPU emulation detected. has appeared in my logcat but i didnt find the enabling Emulation option in my AVD setting..i am using that  ![my SDK is R 21][1]

Answer (score 1):

Edit your AVD and check use Host GPU:

[image]

Edit:
But it does not work for pre ICS emulators.